# js variable is always overwritten with new value

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I try to draw shapes on a HTML5 canvas. These shapes depend on statusses in my database. I do a get to a webservice that returns the statusses for my shapes. That part works. But when I try to use the shape variable in the function part of the get, my shape variable is overwritten by the last status.

I've tried to draw shapes without the get call and that works. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < map_json.shapes.length; i++) {
            var shape = map_json.shapes[i];//variable

            if (!(force && i == active_btn_index) || (i == selected_btn_index)) {
                drawShape(
                    shape.c,
                    map_btns_context,
                    (i == active_btn_index || i == selected_btn_index) ? options_active : options
                );

                if (shape.lotNo != undefined && shape.tc != undefined) {
                    $.getJSON(site_url + "DesktopModules/DNN.WebAPI/API/Ajax/GetStatus?lotNo=" + shape.lotNo,
                        function (data, success) {
                            console.log(shape);
                            //my shape.tc is always overwritten by the last returned data item 
                            map_btns_context.drawImage(map_type_img[data.status], shape.tc[0] - 12, shape.tc[1] - 12);
                        }
                    );
                    //map_btns_context.drawImage(map_type_img[shape.t], shape.tc[0] - 12, shape.tc[1] - 12);
                }
            }

            body += '<area shape="poly" coords="' + shape.c.toString() + '" onmouseover="updateButtons(' + i + ')" />';//title="Shape ' + (i+1) + '" />';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are hitting AJAX in a loop **asynchronously**. By the time your AJAX returns response, the execution moves further and overwrites your *shape* variable by the last item. Try making AJAX hit **synchronously**.

When you remove the AJAX part, the script executes in a synchronous way and your Shape variable always gets the current value.